# cimg wont load lenna image

Tags: c++, cimg

I'm using vs2015, created a win32 c++ console app 
This gives a pure native c++ app, while i got some other examples working.
This demo code doesn't work, the problem seams to the loading of the lenna.png or lenna.jpg

Each time i get errors that the image file isn't recognized. ( i even used the original lenna as from wikipedia) but it doesn't work for some unknown reason, to exclude path problems i even placed lenna at "d:\\lenna.jpg" as well.

I don't know why it won't work, any ideas?

Is cimg just old and doesn't recognize jpg of these days ??

```
#include "CImg.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace cimg_library;

int main() {
 CImg<unsigned char> image("D:\\CODE\\Cimg-prj\\PGT\\Debug\\Lenna.png"), visu(500,400,1,3,0);
 const unsigned char red[] = { 255,0,0 }, green[] = { 0,255,0 }, blue[] = { 0,0,255 };
 image.blur(2.5);
 CImgDisplay main_disp(image,"Click a point"), draw_disp(visu,"Intensity profile");
 while (!main_disp.is_closed() && !draw_disp.is_closed()) {
  main_disp.wait();
  if (main_disp.button() && main_disp.mouse_y()>=0) {
   const int y = main_disp.mouse_y();
   visu.fill(0).draw_graph(image.get_crop(0,y,0,0,image.width()-1,y,0,0),red,1,1,0,255,0);
   visu.draw_graph(image.get_crop(0,y,0,1,image.width()-1,y,0,1),green,1,1,0,255,0);
   visu.draw_graph(image.get_crop(0,y,0,2,image.width()-1,y,0,2),blue,1,1,0,255,0).display(draw_disp);
  }
 }
return 0;
}
```

The errors i get (all output) :

```
Invalid Parameter - "C:\\Users\\Peter\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\kY6GW46A.pnm"
'gm.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Invalid Parameter - "C:\\Users\\Peter\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\as88yC80.pnm"
'gm.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Invalid Parameter - "C:\\Users\\Peter\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\wa804U6G.pnm"
'gm.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

[CImg] * * * CImgIOException * * * [instance(0,0,0,0,00000000,non-shared)] CImg<float>::load(): Failed to recognize format of file 'Lenna.png'.
```

I am sure Lenna.png is a valid png file 
(if i rename its extension irfranview will  try to rename it back as png).

I might not get it to work due to the extra complexity of setting up a project properly for png, i downloaded zlib and libpng, but not sure how to add them to the project (and their a bunch of files?, their not a single dll or .h file like cimg do i need to add all those files ???)

Comment: *Please* indent  your code.

Comment: i was worried the long lines would becomme unreadable, and since the code is short mostly 1 command per line i wrote it like this

Comment: Trust me, it's going to be easier to read it it's indented. Split long lines if you have to.

Answer (score 0):

If you want CImg to be able to load PNG files without relying on ImageMagick, you must tell it so by defining a macro **before** loading the CImg header file;

```
#define cimg_use_png 1
#include "CImg.h"
```

You must also link with library GDI32 and libpng and libz for compression of PNGs.

Comment: For another example (parrot example) i didnt have to link GDI32
is it a requirement for reading png / jpg ?
(btw still have to test your answer, will confirm if it works later today)

Comment: So far i'm unable to make it work, i'm just starting with cimg.
its not clear apperently zlib and libpng are not just some dll's i can add.
Do you know perhaps of example code to get this done.
I'm trying to create a new filter for blender rendered images.
I worked out the image math, but cimg is causing me a headache now

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Visual Studio or Windows - everything works fine and well on Linux and Mac and CImg is certainly not dated. I will look around and see if I can find anything specific to Windows other than GDI32.

Comment: Maybe you could click `edit` under your question and add in your error messages.

Comment: i'm not using visual c++, i'm doing native c++ with vs2015, thats more like c++ on linux, it is cimg that has enough power in itself to display something. (as i saw with another example). but that was with a strange graphics format where Blender uses more often png (or jpg).

Comment: when you link with Libz and libpng, are those single files ? (cause i downloaded then from github and its quite a large collection of files; makes me think i downloaded the source while i only need something compiled that i can link to, but not realy sure about it).